# Conversion correcta en SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo un campo en la tabla que se llama DNI, es un valor en `Float`.
Al ejecutar la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT ISNULL(dni,0) FROM tabla WHERE cod = 1
```

Me devuelve el valor en **0 (cero)** para este caso donde es nulo. Me gustaría saber si puedo hacer que este valor en **0(cero)** sea algo de tipo char, nchar, etc.

Es decir, me gustaría que en vez de cero me devuelva algo como esto: **--** dos guiones medios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con esta linea:

```
SELECT CAST(ISNULL(tabla.DNI,'---') AS VARCHAR(100)) AS DNI from Tabla WHERE tabla.cod = 1
```

si no te funciona así, inténtalo así:

```
SELECT ISNULL(CAST(tabla.DNI AS VARCHAR(100)),'---') AS DNI from Tabla WHERE tabla.cod = 1
```

inténtalo ambas y cuéntanos como te fue.

Comment: Muchas gracias, la segunda me ha funcionado de maravilla.

Answer (score 4):

Simplemente convierte `dni` en un `varchar` para que sea consistente con el valor que quieres para el `NULL`:

```
SELECT ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR, dni),'No disponible') FROM tabla WHERE cod = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT IIF(dni IS NULL, '--', dni) AS dni FROM tabla WHERE cod = 1
```

Comment: No, eso genera esto: `Error al convertir el tipo de datos varchar a float.`

Comment: Sí? Bueno, entonces te recomiendo que cambies el DNI a varchar, que sería lo correcto (porque no creo que necesites hacer ningún cálculo de punto flotante con el DNI)

Comment: Me encantaría poder hacerlo, pero la realidad es que la BD no es mía ni la hice yo, tampoco tengo permisos para modificarla por lo que por eso quería hacer lo que te dije.

Comment: Prueba con lo que edité, lamentablemente no tengo en estos momentos un SQL server para probarlo.